# Java BigInteger Memory Allocation

Tags: java, memory-management, biginteger

We know about declaring objects. My question is regarding that only.

According to Java the following statement is legitimate:

```
BigInteger number = BigInteger.valueOf(2);
```

But the thing I dont understand is how is the memory allocated. We don't use the keyword `new` to allocate memory then how the returned `BigInteger` 2 is stored in number?

Comment: I suggest you should read about static factory methods, e.g. in Effective Java 2nd Edition Item 1.

Answer (score 3):

You are calling a static method `BigInteger.valueOf` which creates an instance of `Biginteger` and returns a reference to it, which you assign to your `number` variable.

Internally, this method creates the instance, using the new keyword, or retrieves a previously created instance from a cache.

```
public static BigInteger valueOf(long val) {
// If -MAX_CONSTANT < val < MAX_CONSTANT, return stashed constant
  if (val == 0)
    return ZERO;
  if (val > 0 && val <= MAX_CONSTANT)
    return posConst[(int) val];
  else if (val < 0 && val >= -MAX_CONSTANT)
    return negConst[(int) -val];

  return new BigInteger(val);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write `BigInteger.valueOf(2)` you are calling the static method of class `BigInteger`. This method in turn creates `BigInteger` object with given value using the `new BigInteger(val)` statement, thus memory allocation occurs there. Using the static method may improve the performance as in several cases already existing object may be returned. For example, `BigInteger.valueOf(0)` will return predefined constant for zero-BigInteger instead of allocating the new object.

Answer (score -1):

This is what happens behind the scene when you call static method `valueOf`

```
public static BigInteger valueOf(long val) {
// If -MAX_CONSTANT < val < MAX_CONSTANT, return stashed constant
 if (val == 0)
     return ZERO;
if (val > 0 && val <= MAX_CONSTANT)
return posConst[(int) val];
else if (val < 0 && val >= -MAX_CONSTANT)
return negConst[(int) -val];

return new BigInteger(val);
}
```

Comment: Don't u see other answers. This is already posted by @Eran. What is new in this answer ?

Comment: Yup I do but after answering , not before answering !!

Comment: Either improve or delete it.